# adb: failed to install split_config.en.apk: Error: must specify a APK size

Tags: android, apk, adb, fastboot

`split_config.en.apk` this is not corrupted packages at all but still adb giving me this response.

```
adb: failed to install split_config.en.apk: Error: must specify a APK size
```

how can i install that package.

Comment: `split_config.en.apk` is only a fraction of an app - it belongs to a so-called split APK file. Usually such a split APK consists of a base apk, a config APK, a languag-specific APK, a display-specific APK and and optional a CPU-architecture specific APK.

Comment: I Have Base.Apk ,  Languag-Specific Apk  And  Split_Config.En.Apk
I Am Installing It Using Adb Shell Pm Install-Create
And Adb Shell Pm Install-Write Where We Write  These Kind Of Split Apk One By One And Then Commit Them All Using Pm  Commit.

Comment: In my opinion `adb install-multiple base.apk, config.apk, ...`  would have been easier.